# Splitting CSV files with commas in the values

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

Using C#, Visual Studio 2013, and Winforms, aiming for .NET 3.5.

Basically, the CSV that we're forced to use for the time being has, at random, values surrounded by quotes, like so:

```
xxxx,,GAS,400,xxx,,89 Stool,,FIELD,ON,23441,USA,1,FFFF,-180.9917,46.4664,0,"87 NORTH BOAT RD, FIELD"
```

When I use this in Excel, the last thing comes out properly as one cell: 87 NORTH BOAT RD, FIELD, despite the comma located within it's value.

However, when I use:

```
private static string[] splitCSVFields(string csvLine)
    {           
        string[] Fields;
        Fields = csvLine.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        return Fields;
    }
```

It removes the Quotation marks, and splits the last value into 87 North Boat RD and FIELD. Is there a way to preserve that value? The major issue is that a split that should yield an array sized 18 returns an array sized 19 and I get out of bounds errors later on.

I've used TextFieldParser, but it causes:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Line 348 cannot be parsed using the current Delimiters.
```

When it gets to the first line (348) that uses a pair of quotes. (IE: The line above is line 348, first use of "" around a field.)

Edit 2: Tested with the duplicate answer, and that fails to solve the issue. It parses the text incorrectly.

Comment: The quotes are how a CSV reader knows that the field contains a literal comma, rather than one used for delimiting the fields. You may want to use a pre-made CSV parser. As you've realized, it's not at all as simple as splitting on commas.

Comment: There's actually one in the framework already: [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The quotes are not "at random" they're surrounding any value that contains a comma.

Comment: The duplicate I was linked to does not have the solution to this problem. The TextParser and the 'duplicate' answer fails to parse properly.